# He lives separate from her. He lives separately from her

Tags: difference, adjectives, adverbs

> He lives separate from her.
>   He lives separately from her.

Which one is correct?
Are these sentences correct?
Please define them with meanings.

Comment: Truthfully, as a native English speaker neither sentence sounds natural. I think given more context there would be a more natural way of saying this.

Answer (score 3):

The grammatically correct one is the one using the adverb: "He lives **separately** from her."

Adverbs modify **verbs**, adjectives, and other adverbs. In this case, the verb 'lives' is being modified by the adverb 'separately'.

How to check if 'separately' really modifies 'lives'? It is through asking if "separately [from her]" answers the question "How does he live?" according to the context.

Answer (score 1):

**It would be "separately"** - separately is an adverb, (because it ends in "ly"), but separate is an adjective.

**Adverbs describe verbs** (these are correct):

> He runs **quickly**
>
> He lives **separately** (from her)

However, you could say:

> He lives in a separate house

Because then, separate is describing the house, and is an adjective.

Comment: Here "separately" describes to what?

Comment: Can you please define my post as you shared your own examples? I mean to say,  settle my post with its own shape.

Comment: @user124234 separately describes the word "lives" --> He lives separately (from her).

Answer (score 0):

Using the word "separately" would be something like this:

> He and she live separately

The best would be something like this:

> He lives apart from her

Comment: According to your point of views, are both sentences correct?